# Modifying the permission requests dialog for push notifications

Tags: cordova, push-notification, cordova-plugins

Does anyone know if it's possible to change IOS && Android push notification messages dialog.  The default is ".. would like to send you push notifications" i would, like to change that text.

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot change the text on that because this generated by default